# Filter a CSV file using Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, csv

I have a file with 12 columns separated by `?`

I need to export column number 12 (NetBIOS Name) and append the whole row to a CSV file. Skip the first line that is the column description.

The first 4 lines af the CSV file expored from a SCCM Query:

```
Name    SMS Assigned Sites  IP Addresses    IP Subnets  Operating System Name and Version   Resource Domain Or Workgroup    Last Logon User Domain  Last Logon User Name    SMS Unique Identifier   Resource ID Resource Type   Netbios Name    
F101-03123D "SIC"   "172.18.1.101"  "172.18.1.0"    Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 5.1    SI  SI  aalmo06 GUID:00003D0D-A754-47ED-B2EA-D29D1C4A4124   3509    System  A202-E1210A 
F112-02478D "SIC"   "169.254.222.155"; "172.18.2.21"    "169.254.0.0"; "172.18.2.0" Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 5.1    SI  SI  aafebep GUID:A4768DE7-E3CA-42B3-90A4-3502B2F04364   3510    System  A234-A1720000B
B567-03565D "SIC"   "172.21.212.6"  "172.21.212.0"  Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 5.1    SI  SI  aabibru GUID:F81E25B7-0074-457A-9E98-1A611208D28B   5438    System  C856-153AE22
```

The result/output CSV file:

```
A202-E1210A
A234-A1720000B
C856-153AE22
etc...
```

I have something like:

```
FOR /F "tokens=12 delims= skip=1 " %%G IN (allsystems.csv) DO @echo %%G
```

But what delimiters should I use here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that the file uses `TAB` as the delimiter. The Windows command prompt uses `TAB` for autocompletion, which means it cannot normally be entered as a regular character. However, you can switch that behaviour off with the following command:

```
cmd /f:off
```

Start the command prompt with that, rather than just `cmd`, and you can now use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to enter the character.

Alternatively, put your script into a batch file. Any text editor will allow you to enter the `TAB` character and the command prompt will have no problem interpreting it as such when you execute the batch file.

Comment: Thanks it works, here is the line: FOR /F "tokens=12 skip=1 delims= " %%G IN (allsystems.csv) DO @echo %%G >>netbios.txt

Comment: !!! unfortunately there is still a problem, it will not get all (NetBIOS Name) in the output ???

Comment: Do those lines still use `TAB` as the delimiter? Is the NetBIOS name in the 12th field? Maybe you can edit your question and post those lines for which that command fails?

Answer (score 0):

Call [CSVfix](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/) from your batch file, designed for exactly this type of task.